# Adding message in Assert.fail()

Tags: java, eclipse, webdriver, testng

I'm using Assert.fail to get list of empty elements. I need to add some text message in `Assert.fail(errorDivs.get(0).getText());`

so I can see that message in report. How can I do that ?

When I add message as

`Assert.fail("Some message",errorDivs.get(0).getText())`

eclipse gives me warning `"The method fail(String, Throwable) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)"`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
Assert.fail( "Some message" + errorDivs.get(0).getText() );
```

Confer the [JavaDoc for `Assert.fail()`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/Assert.html#fail%28java.lang.String%29) - the method takes a single String argument.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You need to send exception about your error, to method `fail()`.

```
Assert.fail("Some message", new Exception(errorDivs.get(0).getText()));
```

Comment: @Anders R. Bystrup solution worked for me. I also tried Alexander Podkutin solution, but it doesn't display message in report.